# Sorting two columns in opposite way

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

Below is what I have

```
id    |  Total    | Area
  1   |    19     |  A
  2   |    20     |  B
  3   |    19     |  C
  4   |    20     |  A
  5   |    19     |  D
```

What I want is as below.

```
id    |  Total    | Area
  4   |    20     |  A
  2   |    20     |  B
  1   |    19     |  A
  3   |    19     |  C
  5   |    19     |  D
```

I was trying as

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY Total, Area DESC
```

By using above code I can sort the Total in descending order, however how to order Area column at the same time? Any idea?

I am closing this question as I got answer

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY Total DESC, Area ASC
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68d64/1)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY Total DESC, Area`?

Comment: @SalmanA : Its woring. I also just got answer as `SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY Total DESC, Area ASC`

Comment: @eggyal : after my comment he answered. so I would be accepting answer... See my comment below to his answer.. I am waiting as SO is asking me to wait for some time to accept answer...

Comment: @eggyal : AND NOW ITS ACCEPTED... :)

Comment: @eggyal : how to undo that?? When I saw SalmanA comment, I had my answer.. so I thought to close question. Then he post the answer (before that I voted). NOW as he asnwered, I marked it as accepted. I want to UNDO the close vote

Comment: I doubt it's worth worrying about; but you could flag for moderator attention if you feel strongly enough!  :)

Comment: @Fahim: on SO questions can be closed for a number of reasons, "found the right answer" is not one of them :) There are always other (and better) ways to accomplish a task and questions should be left open so that others can contribute. Best way to "indicate" that a question has been answered is by accepting the best answer.

Comment: @FahimParkar Please don't approve [suggested edits like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1116994). If needed, refer to this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/165773) for details.

Comment: @gnat : My net was slow and accidently approved was clicked. my bad..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each column/expression in an `ORDER BY` clause can have *its own* order (`ASC/DESC`, `ASC` is the default if not specified). You can write:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY Total DESC, Area /* ASC */
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68d64/1)